# How to use GridSearchCV output for a scikit prediction?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

In the following code:

```
# Load dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

rf_feature_imp = RandomForestClassifier(100)
feat_selection = SelectFromModel(rf_feature_imp, threshold=0.5)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(5000)

model = Pipeline([
          ('fs', feat_selection), 
          ('clf', clf), 
        ])

 params = {
    'fs__threshold': [0.5, 0.3, 0.7],
    'fs__estimator__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'clf__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
 }

 gs = GridSearchCV(model, params, ...)
 gs.fit(X,y)
```

**What should be used for a prediction?**

- `gs`?
- `gs.best_estimator_`?
  or
- `gs.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf']`?

**What is the difference between these 3?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`gs.predict(X_test)` is equivalent to `gs.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)`. Using either, `X_test` will be passed through your entire pipeline and it will return the predictions.

`gs.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'].predict()`, however is only the last phase of the pipeline. To use it, the feature selection step must already have been performed. This would only work if you have previously run your data through `gs.best_estimator_.named_steps['fs'].transform()`

Three equivalent methods for generating predictions are shown below:

Using `gs` directly.

```
pred = gs.predict(X_test)
```

Using `best_estimator_`.

```
pred = gs.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
```

Calling each step in the pipeline individual.

```
X_test_fs = gs.best_estimator_.named_steps['fs'].transform(X_test)
pred = gs.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'].predict(X_test_fs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there an offcial doc saying the same?

Comment: There is no training set!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `True` to the value of `refit` parameter of `GridSearchCV` (which is the default value anyway), then the estimator with best parameters refits on the whole dataset, so you can use `gs.fit(X_test)` for prediction.
If the value of `refit` is equal to `False` while fitting the `GridSearchCV` object on your training set, then for prediction, you have only one option which is using `gs.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)`.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.

Comment: Please refer to the official doc for more info:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html?highlight=gridsearchcv#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

Comment: Where is the training data?